# Why do I get black outlines/edges on a texture in libGDX?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, photoshop

Whenever I draw a texture that has alpha around the edges (it is anti-aliased by photoshop), these edges become dark. I have endlessly messed around with texture filters and blend modes but have had no success.

Here is what I mean:

`minFilter: Linear magFilter: Linear`

[image: Circle on yellow background]
[image: Red background]

`minFilter: MipMapLinearNearest magFilter: Linear`

[image]
[image]

`minFilter: MipMapLinearLinear magFilter: Linear`

[image]
[image]

As you can see, changing the filter on the libGDX **Texture Packer** makes a big difference with how things look, but alphas are **still dark**.

I have tried manually setting the texture filter in libgdx with:

```
texture.setFilter(minFilter, magFilter);
```

But that does not work.

I have read that downscaling with a linear filter causes the alpha pixels to default to black? If this is the case, how can I avoid it?

I have also tried changing the blend mode: `glBlend(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_APHA)` makes no difference. `glBlend(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` removes alpha altogether so that doesn't work.

I do **NOT** want to set my `minFilter` to `Nearest` because it makes things look terribly pixellated. I have tried every other combination of texture filters but everything results in the same black/dark edges/outline effect.

Comment: You can try increasing padding on Sprites if you are using TextureAtlas created with Texture packer. If i remember right, Linear filter check nearest 8 frames to find best pixel and it may cause it be black edges. I actually had this problem but i can't remember how i solved it. I either remade the sprites with PS or changed TexturePacker options. I always set filter inside TexturePacker to linear. Sorry for not being able to post more definitive answer, it's been a while since i used LibGDX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have read that downscaling with a linear filter causes the alpha pixels to default to black?

This is not necessarily true; it depends on what colour Photoshop decided to put in the *fully transparent* pixels. Apparently this is black in your case.

The problem occurs because the GPU is interpolating between two neighbouring pixels, one of which is fully transparent (with all colour channels set to zero as well). Let's say that the other pixel is bright red:

```
(255,   0,   0, 255)  // Bright red, fully opaque
(  0,   0,   0,   0)  // Black, fully transparent
```

Interpolating with a 50/50 ratio gives:

```
(128,   0,   0, 128)
```

This is a half-opaque *dark red* pixel, which explains the dark fringes you're seeing.

There are two possible solutions.

#### 1. Add bleeds to transparent regions

Make sure that the fully transparent pixels have the right colour assigned to them; essentially "bleed" the colour from the nearest non-transparent pixel into adjacent fully transparent pixels. I'm not sure Photoshop can do this, but the libGDX TexturePacker can; see the [`bleed` and `bleedIterations` settings](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#configuration). You need to be careful to set `bleedIterations` high enough, *and* add enough padding for the bleed to expand into, for your particular level of downscaling.

Now the example comes out like this:

```
(255,   0,   0, 255)
(255,   0,   0,   0)  // Red bled into the transparent region
```

Interpolation now gives a bright red transparent pixel, as desired:

```
(255,   0,   0, 128)
```

#### 2. Use premultiplied alpha

This is less finicky to get right, but it helps to know exactly what you're doing. Again TexturePacker has you covered, with the `premultipliedAlpha` setting. This is OpenGL blend mode `glBlend(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.

The numbers in the example don't change; this is still the pixel that comes out:

```
(128,   0,   0, 128)
```

However, this is no longer interpreted as "half-transparent dark red", but rather as "add some red, and remove some background". More generally, with premultiplied alpha, the colour channels are not "which colour to blend in" but "how much colour to add".

Note that a pixel like `(255, 0, 0, 0)` can no longer exist in the source texture: because the alpha is premultiplied, an alpha of zero automatically means that all colour channels must be zero as well. (If you want to get really fancy, you can even use such pixels to apply *additive* blending in the same render pass and the same texture as regular blending!)

Further reading on premultiplied alpha:

- [Shawn Hargreaves' blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha/)
- [Alpha Blending: To Pre or Not To Pre by NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre)

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that TexturePacker-GUI was causing all of the problems. While following your first suggestion I switched to using the command-line TexturePacker, which is maybe more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing filtering on texture packer pro from Linear to MipMap[image]